# How to wait for a certain number of rows?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm testing a webpage and some of its content is loaded with `XMLHttpRequest`. I need to check if my `<table>` contains 2 rows (because the page already contains 1 row when loading) after the Ajax call.

My test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost/index.html");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testIfPartnerListPageIsPresent() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("123")).click();
    List<WebElement> rawList = driver.findElement(By.id("id-213"))
        .findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    assertTrue("More than 1 raw", rawList.size() > 1);
}
```

How can I ask to Selenium to wait for other rows in my table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will wait until the table contains at least given number of rows

```
 public void waitUntilRowPopulates(WebElement element, final int rowCount) {
        final WebElement table = element;

        new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

            public boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                 List<WebElement> rawList = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
                 return (rawList.size() >= rowCount);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is just one problem, the compilation give me an error about the `rawCount` parameter. Are you sure it is accessible from this context?

Comment: @Fractaliste: It should be also marked as `final`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Good answer. A more concise way than to explicitly instantiate a `FluentWait<WebDriver>` would be to use a `WebDriverWait`, which is the exact same specialization of `FluentWait`.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code should help:

```
int noOfRowsBeforeAJAXCall = driver.findElement(By.id("id-213")).findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();
int noOfRowsAfterAJAXCall;

driver.findElement(By.id("123")).click();

while(1)
{
   noOfRowsAfterAJAXCall = driver.findElement(By.id("id-213")).findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();

   // Check whether row nos. increased   
   if(noOfRowsAfterAJAXCall>noOfRowsBeforeAJAXCall)
     break;

   // Re-check after 1 sec
   Thread.sleep(1000m);
}
```

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep()` is not a really good idea when you have other better options like `fluentWait`. Also this code wont compile.  
Hint: `Thread.sleep()` accepts only numbers

Answer (score 0):

For web pages, especially ones that have a lot of content inside, it is advisable to use JSoup library to grab the html, parse inside. This can also be used for the purpose of synchronization.

Sample code:

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageSource);
String someValue = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "specificValue");
```

JSoup has a lot of getter methods that allow flexibility in finding what we want. It supports CSS query as well.